# Add new datasets on GCP object detection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, object-detection, google-vision

I generated a model on Google Vision (object detection) and I wanted to know if I could add new datasets over time, without having to reprocess the already modeled datasets

I take the example of google :

- I have a dataset with roses, tulips ...,
- I have already created a moldel with the flowers
- And I wanted to add a new dataset with just sunflowers,
  without deleting the models of the previous flowers

how I do to add the sunflowers ?

Answer (score 1):

To [add new data](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/create-datasets#import-data) to your dataset *(see Importing images into a non-empty dataset)*:

1. Select the dataset from the Datasets page to go to its details page.
2. On the Dataset details page, select the Import tab.
   Selecting the Import tab will take you to the Create dataset page
3. You can then specify the Google Cloud Storage location of your .csv file and select Import to begin the image import process.

But in your case, you will need to **train a new model**. If you resume training of your existing model, [it will fail](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/train#resumable_training). Because your dataset's labels will be changed by adding the sunflower label.

A model with a different number of labels has a **different underlying structure** (E.g.: the output layer would have more nodes because it has as many nodes as labels) so you can’t resume a model’s training with a dataset that has a different number of labels.

*Note that you can add more data to your existing dataset and resume training but only if you add data for the already existing labels.*